# How to do pagination (from, size) with elastic search aggregation query in nodejs

Tags: javascript, node.js, elasticsearch

I am currently have an API that returns user usage logs to front end but the data is too large so I need pagination. I am not able to do pagination in elastic search aggregation query.
Currently using this code

```
const result = await esClient.search({
      index: 'user-logs',
      body: {
        size: 0,
        query: {
          bool: {
            filter: [
              {
                range: {
                  timestamp: {
                    gte: 1596804771643,
                    lte: 1596904771643,
                    format: 'epoch_millis'
                  }
                }
              },
              {
                query_string: {
                  analyze_wildcard: true,
                  query: `*`
                }
              }
            ]
          }
        },
        aggs: {
          3: {
            terms: {
              field: 'email.keyword',
              size: 10,
              order: {
                _term: 'desc'
              },
              min_doc_count: 1
            },
            aggs: {
              4: {
                terms: {
                  field: 'mobile.keyword',
                  order: {
                    _term: 'desc'
                  },
                  min_doc_count: 1
                },
                aggs: {
                  5: {
                    terms: {
                      field: 'fullName.keyword',
                      order: {
                        _term: 'desc'
                      },
                      min_doc_count: 1
                    },
                    aggs: {
                      6: {
                        terms: {
                          field: 'branchName.keyword',
                          order: {
                            _term: 'desc'
                          },
                          min_doc_count: 1
                        },
                        aggs: {
                          1: {
                            sum: {
                              field: 'timespent'
                            }
                          }
                        }
                      }
                    }
                  }
                }
              }
            }
          }
        }
      }
    });
```

In simple query, I use "from" and "size", but in case of aggregation query, they are not working. I am new to Elastic Search.

Answer (score 0):

The `terms` doesn't support pagination.

Look into [composite aggregations](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/search-aggregations-bucket-composite-aggregation.html#_pagination) w/ [sub-aggregations](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/search-aggregations-bucket-composite-aggregation.html#_sub_aggregations) which indeed do support pagination using `after_key`.

Comment: I am using Elastic Search Version 5.5 and it does not support this    https://stackoverflow.com/a/61497937/12625560

Comment: In that case you'll probably need to loop over some metric (the date range comes into mind) in smaller batches and then merge the agg results.

Comment: Ya that's what I am doing